# Two successive http requests gets the same result in flutter application

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I have a class with static methods to fetch data and use the results with FutureBuilder in my flutter web project.
I make two http post requests and the second one gets the first one's result.
I suspect about concurrent calls and I used awaits. Nonetheless the problem continues.

When below code is executed response.body and response2.body values are equal!
getEntity1ById calls getEntity2s inside.

ServiceConstants.getEntity1Path and  ServiceConstants.getEntity2Path values are different, I checked!

Am I doing smth wrong?

Flutter version is 2.5.3 and http package version is0.13.4

```
class Entity1Services {
  static Future<Entity1> getEntity1ById(String jwt, int id) async {
    Entity1 entity1ToReturn;

    Uri url = Uri.http(
      ServiceConstants.serviceURL,
      ServiceConstants.getEntity1Path,
    );

    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
        "token": jwt,
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
        {
          "id": id,
        },
      ),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> responseJSON = json.decode(response.body);
      var responseDataField = responseJSON["data"];
      if (responseDataField == null) {
        if (responseJSON['resultStatus'] == -1 &&
            responseJSON['info'] != null &&
            responseJSON['info'] != '') {
          throw Exception('Failed to get marina info: ${responseJSON['info']}');
        } else
          throw Exception(
              'Failed to get entity1 info: Null response from service!');
      }

      entity1ToReturn=
          Entity1.fromJson(responseDataField['result'] as Map<String, dynamic>);

      List<Entity2> entity2s = await getEntity2s(jwt);
      entity1ToReturn.entity2s = entity2s ;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to get marina info: Not HTTP 200!');
    }

    return entity1ToReturn;
  }

  static Future<List<Entity2>> getEntity2s(String jwt) async {
    Uri url2 = Uri.http(
      ServiceConstants.serviceURL,
      ServiceConstants.getEntity2sPath,
    );

    final response2 = await http.post(
      url2,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
        "token": jwt,
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
        {},
      ),
    );

    if (response2.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> responseJSON = json.decode(response2.body);
      var responseDataField = responseJSON["data"];
      if (responseDataField == null) {
        if (responseJSON['resultStatus'] == -1 &&
            responseJSON['info'] != null &&
            responseJSON['info'] != '') {
          throw Exception(
              'Failed to get entity2s info: ${responseJSON['info']}');
        } else
          throw Exception(
              'Failed to get entity2s info: Null response from service!');
      }

      return (responseDataField['result'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((e) => Entity2.fromJson(e))
          .toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to get entity 2s: Not HTTP 200!');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is the url same for both the requests?

Comment: No, I debugged and checked the urls. url1 and url2 are different paths.

Comment: just check that response and response2 have same data or not if not then your functions are conflicting each other somewhere inside.

Comment: response and response2 have different data. Then it seems like a bug of http package? I suppose I am not the first person in the world who makes to consecutive http post requests.

Comment: if http package had some bug then it will not return you different response data the bug is in your code somewhere check twice.

Comment: OMG! I found it. The paths are different but the second one was wrong :( Thank you for your patience about me and answering my questions. I sometimes seek error somewhere else than my code :)

Comment: pleased to help :)